# Simplifying an infinite series with variable in the summand

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

Hello fellow mathematicians! This is my first post - what better way to start this lovely journey than with an infinite series.

I would like to simplify the following sum, which I know converges (I have applied the ratio test).

Let $n = 1, 2, 3, ...$ and $0 < x < 1$.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x(1-x)^n \times \log_{2}\left(x\left(1-x\right)^{n}\right)$

It's easy to see why this would converge. $(1-p)$ is clearly less than $1$ for $0<p<1$. Since we are raising this term to an exponent, it will decay to $0$ - so the sum is well defined. But how can I obtain a simplified form of the above sum? This is what I am struggling with. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: you can move the multiplication by $x$ outside the sum. You can also use the logarithm laws to expand out the log as $\log_2(x) + n\log_2(1 - x)$. Rearranging and moving more terms out of the sum will reduce it to the sum of a geometric series and something close to the derivative of a geometric series.